# How can I create a mean-value for repeating factors?

Tags: r, filter, mean

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPJgP.png)

I am modifying a dataset to be able to conduct a statistical test with it. As you can see (picture attached)there are cases, where countries appear more than ones within a fiscal year (data relates to military aid given to countries by the USA) and I want to modify my data that for these cases a yearly mean exists, so that every country only is given ones in a fiscal year.
How can I do this?

```
military_struct <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Fiscal.Year,              ~Region,                   ~Country, ~Assistance.Category,                                ~Publication.Row,       ~Funding.Agency,                           ~Funding.Account.Name, ~Obligations..Historical.Dollars., ~Obligations..Constant.Dollars.,
        "2001", "Sub-Saharan Africa",                    "Benin",           "Military", "International Military Education and Training", "Department of State", "International Military Education and Training",                          "384000",            "540889.77955911809",
        "2001", "Sub-Saharan Africa",                 "Botswana",           "Military",                    "Foreign Military Financing", "Department of State",            "Foreign Military Financing Program",                         "1597000",            "2249481.7134268531",
        "2001", "Sub-Saharan Africa",                 "Botswana",           "Military", "International Military Education and Training", "Department of State", "International Military Education and Training",                          "663000",            "933880.01002003974",
        "2001", "Sub-Saharan Africa",                 "Cameroon",           "Military", "International Military Education and Training", "Department of State", "International Military Education and Training",                          "223000",            "314110.47094188369",
        "2001", "Sub-Saharan Africa",               "Cabo Verde",           "Military", "International Military Education and Training", "Department of State", "International Military Education and Training",                          "126000",            "177479.45891783561",
        "2001", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Central African Republic",           "Military", "International Military Education and Training", "Department of State", "International Military Education and Training",                          "116000",            "163393.78757515026",
        "2001", "Sub-Saharan Africa",                     "Chad",           "Military", "International Military Education and Training", "Department of State", "International Military Education and Training",                          "173000",            "243682.11422845683",
        "2001", "Sub-Saharan Africa",      "Congo (Brazzaville)",           "Military", "International Military Education and Training", "Department of State", "International Military Education and Training",                           "86000",            "121136.77354709416",
        "2001", "Sub-Saharan Africa",                 "Djibouti",           "Military",                    "Foreign Military Financing", "Department of State",            "Foreign Military Financing Program",                          "100000",            "140856.71342685368",
        "2001", "Sub-Saharan Africa",                 "Djibouti",           "Military", "International Military Education and Training", "Department of State", "International Military Education and Training",                          "132000",            "185930.86172344684"
  )
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Of course, I edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to get this?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(janitor) # using to clean the column names a bit


military_struct <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Fiscal.Year,              ~Region,                   ~Country, ~Assistance.Category,                                ~Publication.Row,       ~Funding.Agency,                           ~Funding.Account.Name, ~Obligations..Historical.Dollars., ~Obligations..Constant.Dollars.,
        "2001", "Sub-Saharan Africa",                    "Benin",           "Military", "International Military Education and Training", "Department of State", "International Military Education and Training",                          "384000",            "540889.77955911809",
        "2001", "Sub-Saharan Africa",                 "Botswana",           "Military",                    "Foreign Military Financing", "Department of State",            "Foreign Military Financing Program",                         "1597000",            "2249481.7134268531",
        "2001", "Sub-Saharan Africa",                 "Botswana",           "Military", "International Military Education and Training", "Department of State", "International Military Education and Training",                          "663000",            "933880.01002003974",
        "2001", "Sub-Saharan Africa",                 "Cameroon",           "Military", "International Military Education and Training", "Department of State", "International Military Education and Training",                          "223000",            "314110.47094188369",
        "2001", "Sub-Saharan Africa",               "Cabo Verde",           "Military", "International Military Education and Training", "Department of State", "International Military Education and Training",                          "126000",            "177479.45891783561",
        "2001", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Central African Republic",           "Military", "International Military Education and Training", "Department of State", "International Military Education and Training",                          "116000",            "163393.78757515026",
        "2001", "Sub-Saharan Africa",                     "Chad",           "Military", "International Military Education and Training", "Department of State", "International Military Education and Training",                          "173000",            "243682.11422845683",
        "2001", "Sub-Saharan Africa",      "Congo (Brazzaville)",           "Military", "International Military Education and Training", "Department of State", "International Military Education and Training",                           "86000",            "121136.77354709416",
        "2001", "Sub-Saharan Africa",                 "Djibouti",           "Military",                    "Foreign Military Financing", "Department of State",            "Foreign Military Financing Program",                          "100000",            "140856.71342685368",
        "2001", "Sub-Saharan Africa",                 "Djibouti",           "Military", "International Military Education and Training", "Department of State", "International Military Education and Training",                          "132000",            "185930.86172344684"
  )


military_struct %>% 
  clean_names() %>% # cleaning the column name a bit
  mutate(
    across(starts_with("obligations"), as.numeric)
  ) %>% 
  group_by(fiscal_year, country) %>% 
    summarise(
      across(where(is.numeric), mean, na.rm = TRUE, .names = "mean_{.col}"),
      .groups = "drop"
    )

#> # A tibble: 8 × 4
#>   fiscal_year country                  mean_obligations_histor… mean_obligation…
#>   <chr>       <chr>                                       <dbl>            <dbl>
#> 1 2001        Benin                                      384000          540890.
#> 2 2001        Botswana                                  1130000         1591681.
#> 3 2001        Cabo Verde                                 126000          177479.
#> 4 2001        Cameroon                                   223000          314110.
#> 5 2001        Central African Republic                   116000          163394.
#> 6 2001        Chad                                       173000          243682.
#> 7 2001        Congo (Brazzaville)                         86000          121137.
#> 8 2001        Djibouti                                   116000          163394.
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: YES !!! Thank you very much for your help! I will try it out in my big dataset

Comment: I have upvoted it (I dont known if you can see it, I dont have many points on here). The code runs but the data is not summarizing like it did in what you have sent. Botswana for example is still appearing twice for the year 2001 and no mean has happened for the obligations-variable.

Comment: Oh, you cannot upvote it right now, but you can accept the answer if it is ok.

Comment: And,  One reason I can think of right now for `Botswana` appearing twice if there's some extra space in the name, that is `Botswana` and ` Botswana` is not same. So can you check on that? Otherwise each country should appear only once for each `fiscal_year`.

Comment: Thank you so much! The was a comma missing in the code. Now it worked perfectly! Ones I figure out how to accept your answer I will immediately do it. Thanks again!